# GWT as offline app, to be deployed onto an iPad

Tags: gwt, ipad

I often use GWT for web UIs. I have heard of it being used a fair bit in conjunction with Gears for offline solutions (probably nowadays HTML5 "offline storage" is all the rage) and I'd like to experiment with building a GUI in GWT and use it on my iPad. Tips/tutorials on how to deploy it onto the device to act as much as possible like a resident "App"? This is just a curiosity/experiment to fill a week-end... (I can "free" the iPad for the experiment if need be yet I am sure a lot can be done without doing so...)

Answer (score 1):

phonegap(now Apache cordova) makes available the ios/android native features like camera,device file management,contacts,geolocation etc to our app.
[GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/) and [mgwt](https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/GettingStarted) :::
Using mgwt,gwt( both are opensource) and GwtPhonegap we can develop cross platform mobile applications which can behave exactly like native apps. in performance perspective these apps are bit slow when compared with native apps but the convenience is that the app can be installed in multiple platforms.

[GwtPhonegap](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/wiki/GettingStarted)
GwtPhonegap acts like a bridge(provides abstraction) between device native functionalities and to our app. We can get good look and feel using css. 
We have support for gwt-html5-database for which to perform cache storage.[gwt-html5](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using gwt in conjunction with phone gap.  It will expose many of the native Apis to make them available for use in gwt.

https://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/wiki/GettingStarted

Additionally I've had very good experiences using the m-gwt as a UI framework.  MGWT makes creating native looking UIs using CSS+JS very easy.

http://www.m-gwt.com/